# SublimeLinter: WARNING: jshint cannot locate 'jshint'

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I am using Windows. I installed Node.js.

> SublimeLinter: WARNING: jshint cannot locate 'jshint'

I'm getting this error. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `npm install jshint --global`.

Comment: Try `npm cache clean`, followed by `sudo npm install -g npm`, then retry the `npm install jshint --global` from your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

This works for linux as well.

Do the following:

1- npm install jshint --global

If you still cant use it follow next steps:

2- In the User file you have to add jshint and node path now. You can find the these paths from your terminal using  `whereis node` and `whereis jshint` .

3- Go to Preferences > Package settings > sublimeLinter > settings
Now add the paths in the user file

```
{"paths":{
    "windows":[YOUR WINDOWS JSHINT PATH],
    "linux":[YOUR LINUX JSHINT PATH]
},
"linters":{
    "jshint":{
        "env":{"PATH":YOUR NODE PATH}
    }
}}
```